# What word would be used for someone who eats meat but not meat products?

Tags: single-word-requests

As described in the various answers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/345315/233202), there are words out there for people who eat poultry and/or fish while not meat. Is there a word for a person who eats meat, fish, poultry, and plants but not their byproducts (dairy and eggs)?

Comment: Perhaps *paleolithic*?

Comment: I would think there might be a word for people who don't eat _processed_ meats etc.

Comment: If an egg is a byproduct from a chicken, isn't a cow (nee calf) a byproduct from another cow?

Comment: @Drew Perhaps. Maybe byproduct isn't the best word to use, though I suppose this is the one site that should be concerned about semantics.

Comment: Unless you can produce evidence that there are such people, there is no reason to expect there to be a word for them.

Comment: @ColinFine (I ask because such a word would describe me.)

Comment: Descriptively it's vegan plus meat, fish, and poultry.

Comment: @Xanne Yes, except that's just about everything vegan is opposed to. :D